# Can characters inside a submit button be formatted differently?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a form and the form has a submit button with html code like this:

```
<input type='Submit' name='sel' value='Submit Here'>
```

I want the word "Submit" to have font-size of 10px and black color while the word "Here" to have font-size of 12px and red color. Is it doable without using back-ground image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Whatever style you add to the input element will be applied to the whole text, you won't be able to select individual characters. However, you can use a different element that supports content, such as a button, where you can add the content you want and style it...

```
<button type="submit">
   <span class="black">Submit</span> <span class="red">Here</span>
</button>
```

And then apply the styles...

```
span.black {font-size:10px;color:black}
span.red{font-size:12px;color:Red}
```

An example below...

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zX7gb/)